# Image to Fade In during input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new to JavaScript and JQuery so i just wanted to ask how can i make an image to fade-in next to an input tag ONLY when i start typing in the input field? 
How should i write my onchange function in JavaScript.

This is my code so far

Thank you in advance

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

   <img id="logo" src="visa.png" style="display:none"/>

   <input id="test" type="text">

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#logo').hide().fadeIn(3000);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img id="logo" src="visa.png" style="display:none" />
<input id="test" type="text" />

<script type="text/javascript">

     $('#test').keypress(function() {
         $('#logo').fadeIn(3000);
     });


</script>
```

Is it what you are looking for ?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s1h49r39/)

Edit : For your second question, if I understood correctly your need, this should do the trick : [JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/s1h49r39/1/)

Comment: I am sorry! Yes! This is what i was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: One last question, Can i make an image fade ininside an input tag align to the right like a glyphicon in Bootstrap 3?

Comment: I added a second jsfiddle for your extra question